# Error while installing psycopg2 on Fedora 21

Tags: linux, psycopg2, fedora-21

Can anyone help me with installing psycopg2?
I have:

```
 - Fedora 21 3.19.5-200.fc21.x86_64 GNU/Linux;
 - Python 2.7.8;
 - Python 3.4.1;
 - virtualenv 12.1.1;
 - pip 6.1.1 (python 3.4) in virtualenv activated;
```

For psycopg2 I installed packages (when trying to solve problem):

```
 - postgresql-devel
 - python3-devel
 - python-devel
 - libpqxx-devel
 - libpqxx
```

But I still get the error while "pip install psycopg2".

Output:

```
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached psycopg2-2.6.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: psycopg2
  Running setup.py install for psycopg2
    Complete output from command /home/dkhabarov/Projects/poll/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-mqhuy9y5/psycopg2/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-z4g3k4um-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/dkhabarov/Projects/poll/include/site/python3.4/psycopg2:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2
    copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2
    copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2
    copying lib/psycopg1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2
    copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2
    copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2
    copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2
    copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2
    copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2
    copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_bugX000.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_notify.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_connection.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_cursor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_with.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/testutils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_green.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_module.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_psycopg2_dbapi20.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_types_extras.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_copy.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/dbapi20_tpc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_lobject.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_dates.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_cancel.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_transaction.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_types_basic.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_extras_dictcursor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_quote.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/testconfig.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_async.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/test_bug_gc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests
    copying tests/dbapi20.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg2/tests
    Skipping implicit fixer: buffer
    Skipping implicit fixer: idioms
    Skipping implicit fixer: set_literal
    Skipping implicit fixer: ws_comma
    running build_ext
    building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090306 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I. -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/pgsql/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
    Command "/home/dkhabarov/Projects/poll/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-mqhuy9y5/psycopg2/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-z4g3k4um-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/dkhabarov/Projects/poll/include/site/python3.4/psycopg2" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-mqhuy9y5/psycopg2
```

Comment: Can you look for pip's /var/log for this error and post it?

Answer (score 2):

Check installed gcc, if no:

```
sudo yum install gcc
```